# Is there a browser which will allow RequestAnimationFrame in a background window (for testing purposes, macOS)

Tags: javascript, browser, requestanimationframe

I have a simulation with animation running in a browser window written in javascript. I'd like to test this running for a long time in the background, but as soon as the window/tab becomes hidden no more RequestAnimationFrame events are triggered. It also stops when the screen saver starts or the screen dims. The computer (macOS) keeps running.

This is normal browser behaviour and also good because if this was easy it would be hijacked galore.

Is there a browser that has enabling RequestAnimationFrame for background windows as a developer option?

I am already using timeOut for other purposes in the simulation/animation.

Comment: On my version of Chrome, if I go to `chrome://flags/#intensive-wake-up-throttling` in the browser bar there is a tab performance throttling of timers on non-focused tabs that can be disabled; you can see if disabling it resolves your issue.  You might also search in this flags view and see if you can find similar features that can be disabled.

Comment: Hmm, not available in my version of Chrome, it seems. Version 90.0.4430.85 on macOS. Anything I should do to make it available?

Comment: No, you're correct-- I just updated from v89 to v90 and lost that option as well.  FWIW [this page on developer.google.com](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/background_tabs#requestanimationframe) points out that this is the expected, documented behavior of `requestAnimationFrame`.  You could look into using [extensions to prevent this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/force-background-tab/gidlfommnbibbmegmgajdbikelkdcmcl?hl=en) (proceed with caution), or look into launching w/ https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-launcher to see if you can set a flag to allow it?